# Get controller name and java service path in controller advice

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-java-sdk, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Hi All i have created a global exception handler in my spring boot app and writing the exception occurred in AWS cloudwatch below code working fine i am able to write the exception in cloudwatch but the challenge is i am unable to get the Restcontroller name and service path from where the the particular exception happened.

**Sample java service**

```
@GetMapping(value = "DynamoDb/deleteTable")
public String deleteTable(@RequestParam String TableName) throws InterruptedException {
     Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(TableName);
        try {
            table.delete();
            table.waitForDelete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return "Success";
    }
```

When ever exception occurred it control transferred to controlleradvice global exception handler

**Here is my code**

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatchlogs.CloudWatchLogsClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatchlogs.model.DescribeLogStreamsRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatchlogs.model.DescribeLogStreamsResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatchlogs.model.InputLogEvent;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatchlogs.model.PutLogEventsRequest;

import java.util.Arrays;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> exceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
        error.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        error.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        error.setController(ex.getMessage());
        error.setService(ex.getMessage());
        error.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        PutLogEvents(error);
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(error, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    public static void PutLogEvents(ErrorResponse Er)
    {
        String regionId = "us-east-1";
        String logGroupName = "xxxxxxx";
        String logStreamName = "xxxxxxx";

        CloudWatchLogsClient logsClient = CloudWatchLogsClient.builder().region(Region.of(regionId)).build();

        // A sequence token is required to put a log event in an existing stream.
        // Look up the stream to find its sequence token.
        String sequenceToken = getNextSequenceToken(logsClient, logGroupName, logStreamName);

        // Build a JSON log using the EmbeddedMetricFormat.

        String message = "[{" +
                "  \"Timestamp\": " + Er.getTimestamp()  + "," +
                "  \"ErrorCode\": " + Er.getErrorCode()  + "," +
                "  \"ControllerName\": " + Er.getErrorCode()  + "," +
                "  \"ServiceName\": " + Er.getErrorCode()  + "," +
                "  \"ErrorMsg\": " + Er.getErrorCode()   + "" +
                "}]";
        InputLogEvent inputLogEvent = InputLogEvent.builder()
                .message(message)
                .timestamp(Er.getTimestamp())
                .build();

        // Specify the request parameters.
        PutLogEventsRequest putLogEventsRequest = PutLogEventsRequest.builder()
                .logEvents(Arrays.asList(inputLogEvent))
                .logGroupName(logGroupName)
                .logStreamName(logStreamName)
                // Sequence token is required so that the log can be written to the
                // latest location in the stream.
                .sequenceToken(sequenceToken)
                .build();

        logsClient.putLogEvents(putLogEventsRequest);
    }

    private static String getNextSequenceToken(CloudWatchLogsClient logsClient, String logGroupName, String logStreamName) {
        DescribeLogStreamsRequest logStreamRequest = DescribeLogStreamsRequest.builder()
                .logGroupName(logGroupName)
                .logStreamNamePrefix(logStreamName)
                .build();

        DescribeLogStreamsResponse describeLogStreamsResponse = logsClient.describeLogStreams(logStreamRequest);

        // Assume that a single stream is returned since a specific stream name was
        // specified in the previous request.
        return describeLogStreamsResponse.logStreams().get(0).uploadSequenceToken();
    }

}
```

**Errorresponse.class**

```
public class ErrorResponse {
    private int errorCode;
    private String message;
    private String Controller;
    private String Service;
    private String ProjectName;
    private long Timestamp;

    public ErrorResponse(int errorCode, String message, String controller, String service, String projectName, long timestamp) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.message = message;
        Controller = controller;
        Service = service;
        ProjectName = projectName;
        Timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public ErrorResponse() {

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ErrorResponse{" +
                "errorCode=" + errorCode +
                ", message='" + message + '\'' +
                ", Controller='" + Controller + '\'' +
                ", Service='" + Service + '\'' +
                ", ProjectName='" + ProjectName + '\'' +
                ", Timestamp=" + Timestamp +
                '}';
    }

    public int getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getController() {
        return Controller;
    }

    public void setController(String controller) {
        Controller = controller;
    }

    public String getService() {
        return Service;
    }

    public void setService(String service) {
        Service = service;
    }

    public String getProjectName() {
        return ProjectName;
    }

    public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
        ProjectName = projectName;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return Timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        Timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

Could any one please help me how can i get the Restcontroller name and service path in Global exception handler?

Comment: You need to post a comment to my answer instead of trying to edit it.

Comment: Add a method argument of type [`HandlerMethod`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod.html) to get the name of the method and enclosing controller. An [`@ExceptionHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler-args) annotated method can use quite a few different types of arguments.

Comment: By using the code **Class controllerClass = handlerMethod.getMethod().getDeclaringClass();** i am able to get the controller name

Comment: Any idea how to get **java service path or method name** using handler method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi All Thanks to all by using below code i am able to get the result as suggested by client. Hope this may help some one. Thanks

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.MethodParameter;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatchlogs.CloudWatchLogsClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatchlogs.model.DescribeLogStreamsRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatchlogs.model.DescribeLogStreamsResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatchlogs.model.InputLogEvent;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatchlogs.model.PutLogEventsRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    @Value("${application.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    @Value("${aws.logGroupName}")
    private String logGroupName;

    @Value("${aws.logStreamName}")
    private String logStreamName;


    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> exceptionHandler(Exception ex, HandlerMethod handlerMethod, HttpServletRequest request) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Class ControllerName = handlerMethod.getMethod().getDeclaringClass();
        String MethodName = handlerMethod.getMethod().getName();
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();

        error.setErrorCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        error.setErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
        error.setControllerName(ControllerName.toString());
        error.setServiceName(MethodName.toString());
        error.setTimeStamp(sdf.format(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        error.setProjectName(applicationName);
        error.setServicePath(request.getRequestURL().toString());
        PutLogEvents(error);

        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(error, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    public void PutLogEvents(ErrorResponse Er) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String regionId = "xxxxx";
        String logGroupName = "xxxxx";
        String logStreamName = "xxxxx";

        CloudWatchLogsClient logsClient = CloudWatchLogsClient.builder().region(Region.of(regionId)).build();
        // A sequence token is required to put a log event in an existing stream.
        // Look up the stream to find its sequence token.
        String sequenceToken = getNextSequenceToken(logsClient, logGroupName, logStreamName);

        // Build a JSON log using the EmbeddedMetricFormat.

        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        String json = ow.writeValueAsString(Er);

        String message =json;
        InputLogEvent inputLogEvent = InputLogEvent.builder()
                .message(message)
                .timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .build();

        // Specify the request parameters.
        PutLogEventsRequest putLogEventsRequest = PutLogEventsRequest.builder()
                .logEvents(Arrays.asList(inputLogEvent))
                .logGroupName(logGroupName)
                .logStreamName(logStreamName)
                // Sequence token is required so that the log can be written to the
                // latest location in the stream.
                .sequenceToken(sequenceToken)
                .build();

        logsClient.putLogEvents(putLogEventsRequest);
    }

    private static String getNextSequenceToken(CloudWatchLogsClient logsClient, String logGroupName, String logStreamName) {
        DescribeLogStreamsRequest logStreamRequest = DescribeLogStreamsRequest.builder()
                .logGroupName(logGroupName)
                .logStreamNamePrefix(logStreamName)
                .build();

        DescribeLogStreamsResponse describeLogStreamsResponse = logsClient.describeLogStreams(logStreamRequest);

        // Assume that a single stream is returned since a specific stream name was
        // specified in the previous request.
        return describeLogStreamsResponse.logStreams().get(0).uploadSequenceToken();
    }

}
```

**Result should be like this**

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Table already exists: ProductFgh (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceInUseException; Request ID: 6S14VS0E6ESUMG55DL937IC42JVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)",
    "timeStamp": "2020-Jan-22 11:53:58",
    "errorCode": 500,
    "projectName": "DynamoDB",
    "servicePath": "http://localhost:8090/DynamoDb/createTable",
    "controllerName": "class com.example.DynamoDB.DynamoDBController",
    "serviceName": "createExampleTable"
}
```

As of now i have achieved this through above code if any better approach is available let me know. Thanks to all

Comment: How are you passing `HandlerMethod handlerMethod` from the service when the exception is called?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the class name from which the exception was thrown as follows:

```
ex.getStackTrace()[0].getClassName();
```

Comment: I am getting result like this **com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor**