# Controller Advice exception handling

Tags: java, spring-boot

In Spring Boot 3 I am using `Controller Advice` to handle a database uniqueness exception and create a custom error message which I can pass in JSON and log.

I would like to add information from MethodHandler so I can also log/add to custom message the URI and Controller that had the exception.

This is how it is setup so far:

**Controller**

```
/**
 * Update Car (PUT)
 */
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = "application/json")
ResponseEntity<CarCreateDto> updateCarDto(@Valid @RequestBody CarCreateDto updateCar, @PathVariable Long id) {
        CarCreateDto Car = CarService.updateCar(updateCar, id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(Car, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Exception Handler**

```
    @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity dataIntegrityViolantionException(final DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setDateFormat(df);
    ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage();
    String mostSpecificCauseMessage = e.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage();
    if (e.getCause().getCause() instanceof SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) {
        try {
            String jsonMessage =  objectMapper.writeValueAsString(errorMessage.builder()
                    .reasonCode(ErrorMessage.ReasonCode.NAME_ALREADY_EXISTS)
                    .message(mostSpecificCauseMessage)
                    .timeStamp(df.format(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .build());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(jsonMessage, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Unknown Data Integrity Violation Exception with message : " +mostSpecificCauseMessage, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
}
```

The example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59824851/get-controller-name-and-java-service-path-in-controller-advice) is very similar to what I want to do - however it does not show how to catch the exception on the controller *and* pass in the relevant instance of `HandlerMethod` so that I can add:

```
    Class ControllerName = handlerMethod.getMethod().getDeclaringClass();
    String MethodName = handlerMethod.getMethod().getName();
```

Controller name and Method name to Error Message.

Is it just a case of adding a try catch to the controller method and passing HandlerMethod as a parameter?

Comment: You shouldn't need to catch the exception in the controller, that is handled for you.

Comment: So how do you get access to HandlerMethod in ControllerAdvice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [Spring MVC can inject many arguments in the exception handler method signature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-controller/ann-exceptionhandler.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler-args), one of them being the `HandlerMethod`:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public ResponseEntity dataIntegrityViolantionException(final DataIntegrityViolationException e, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {

  // you can get the information you need with
  String message = handlerMethod.getShortLogMessage();

  // or extract more precise information
  Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't catch the exception in Controller, ControllerAdvice will catch it based on the exception class of this defined `@ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)`. This means whenever your controller throws `DataIntegrityViolationException` exception, it will be passed to method `dataIntegrityViolantionException`.

I guess you need to throw a `DataIntegrityViolationException` in `CarService` class to make it work like your expectation.

Comment: Can't do it in CarService because of @Transactional.

Comment: @RayBond Can you explain in detail? because if you throw it, Transaction will be rollback?